# angularjs toggle button show list items on next view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

First off i would like to say I am fairly new to Angularjs but I am learning the basics of it pretty well.

The goal of my angular app is to have 2 pages in [AngularJS UI-Router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router). I got to that part of my app pretty well and the documentation is good. My goal now is to pass data/selection/attributes from Home page to about page. So If I was to have a list of select buttons on home page, it would show/hide another list on the about page. So selections on Home page would be remembered on Home page.

I have read the documentation on factories, service and rootScope about it and I am still confused. What and how can I pass select Boolean value into factory, then inject that value/data to About page and then hide/show items?

I have something already set up on Home page but in terms of input box (which is a good first step but not what im looking for) that shows data on About page. The data is remembered in the current browser session.

How to insert ng-toggle, ng-click or any variable controller scope data into the factory? How do I inject that boolean value to About page.

Here is my current Plunker solution: [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/skWQHE90Qk99AKpylR5h?p=preview)

My plunker app angular code

```js
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    
    $stateProvider
        
        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })
        
        
        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'partial-about.html'
        });
        
});



routerApp.factory('MyService', function(){
  return {
    data: {
    }
    // Other methods or objects can go here?
  };
});

routerApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, MyService){
  $scope.data = MyService.data;
});

routerApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, MyService){
   $scope.data = MyService.data;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="routerApp">
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .navbar { border-radius:0; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your service to this:

```
this.data = {};
// Other methods or objects can go here?    

return this;
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kgfEl87cybKxEoAtQnZ4) is a working plunker.